# How to combine two similar http requests returning Rx Observables?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

How do I merge 2 separate http requests into one response(join them)?

```
Observable.merge(
  this.http.get(url1), // [{"city":"New York"},{"city":"Chicago"}]
  this.http.get(url2)  // [{"city":"Washington"},{"city":"Detroit"}]
).subscribe(res => console.log(res.json()))
```

I'm getting two arrays back:

```
[{"city":"New York"},{"city":"Chicago"}],
[{"city":"Washington"},{"city":"Detroit"}]
```

What I need is a single array with the combined results:

```
[{"city":"New York"},{"city":"Chicago"},{"city":"Washington"},{"city":"Detroit"}]
```

I.e., one observable of 4 objects, not 2 observables of 2 objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want `forkJoin` (which becomes [Zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) operator) which returns an observable sequence with an array collecting the last elements of all the input sequences:

```
combine(): {
  return Observable.forkJoin(
    this.http.get(url1).map(res => res.json()),
    this.http.get(url2).map(res => res.json())
  )
}

...

  this.combine().subscribe(result => 
    console.log(result[0], result[1])
  )
```

Also you may be interesting in [combainLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) operator.

---

**UPD** To get a combined result you may use `map` and spread operator:

```
combine(): {
  return Observable.forkJoin(
    this.http.get(url1).map(res => res.json()),
    this.http.get(url2).map(res => res.json())
  )
  .map((data: any[]) => ([...data[0], ...data[1]])
}

...

  this.combine().subscribe(result => 
    console.log(result)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it gives me 2 results of 2 cities, not 1 result of 4 cities.

Comment: @johnerfx Sorry, I misread the issue. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Observable.merge(
  this.http.get(url1).pipe(mergeMap(a => a)), 
  this.http.get(url2.pipe(mergeMap(a => a))  
).subscribe(res => console.log(res.json()))
```