# Observable sequence with dependencies

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I want to combine two http get requests.
They should be executed after each other and the second one gets a part of the first ones result as a parameter.

The combined request then should return a list like:
[first result json, seconds result json]

I've already found this on stackoverflow: [How to combine two similar http requests returning Rx Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003275/how-to-combine-two-similar-http-requests-returning-rx-observables)

With forkJoin I can combine the two requests.

```
return forkJoin(
    this.spotify.getSpotifyData(spotifyId),
    this.youtube.getYoutubeData(PARAMETER HERE)
);
```

How can I take the result from the first as a parameter of the second one?

**UPDATE**
This question got marked as a duplicate of [How to finalize nested Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57638183/how-to-finalize-nested-observables) but that solution does not work for me.

Here's my updated code:

```
return this.spotify.getSpotifyData(spotifyId).pipe(
    switchMap(
        spotifyResult => {
            return this.youtube.getYoutubeData(spotifyResult["name"]).pipe(
                map(
                    youtubeVideoResult => {
                        ({spotifyResult, youtubeVideoResult})
                    })
                )
        }
    )
)
```

Then I subscribe like this: (note: getDataBySpotifyId method is the one from above)

```
getDataBySpotifyId(id).subscribe(
    ({data,data2}) => {
        console.log("data: " + data);
    }
)
```

and I get the following error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: I think you has a type error sintax, is `map(youtubeVideoResult=>{[spotifyResult,youtubeVideoResult])` -see the "["- and `subscribe([data,data2])` -again the "[", not "{"

Comment: No, by changing to [] I get the following error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqymu3 I just write a simple example (in the example I use of(..) to create two observables -in your case replace by this.spotify.getSpotyData and this.youtube.getYoutubeData-, but must be work

Comment: this works, thanks! but I don't know where the difference is

Comment: take account yours "{", e.g. you write map(x=>[x,y]) or you write map(x=>{return [x,y]}). see that if we use "{" we need use return. I updated the stackblitz to show the two ways